# Threat Model for a third party messaging application for an organisation

Tags: threat-modeling

Are there any templates or guides anywhere which illustrate how threat models should be documented?

For example, what kind of threats are there for cloud-based/ third party instant messaging services? Would you use STRIDE (Spoofing, Tampering, Repudiation, Information disclosure, DoS, Elevatation) as a reference point? What kind of diagrams do you need?

Looking for some overall guidance to help explain how they would go about producing a threat model analysis for a third party / cloud based messaging service.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed. Please feel free to come back with a more detailed question describing your actual problem.

Comment: This is not a product recommendation, but a request for a type of drawing or process.

Comment: Yes I am looking for someone to help explain how they would go about producing a threat model analysis for a third party / cloud based  messaging service. I'm am not looking for any product recommendations. Thanks.

Comment: Clearly this is process not product.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at your tag, are you searching for application threat modeling?

One great place to start would be at OWASP, they have the following guides and some templates to illustrate threat models.

For myself, i'm referencing both OWASP and SANS articles. Here a link to OWASP.

[OWASP Application Threat Modeling](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Application_Threat_Modeling)

[OWASP Threat Risk Modeling](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Threat_Risk_Modeling)

SANS has their own threat modeling article as well, you can easily search for it in google.

[SANS Application Threat Modeling](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/securecode/threat-modeling-process-ensure-application-security-1646)

Comment: Additional article form OWASP
[Threat Risk Modeling from OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Threat_Risk_Modeling)

Sans has their own threat modeling article as well

[Application Security Threat Modeling](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/securecode/threat-modeling-process-ensure-application-security-1646)

Comment: you can update your answer itself. It's better than adding comments to your own answer.

Comment: Couldn't add more than 1 link as a new user. Thanks for reminding @Limit

Comment: HI Lester, Yes I'm looking at producing a threat model analysis for a third party messaging service. Thanks for the links, will check them out!

Comment: Cool. Glad to help.